# which partition should i add to free space on /?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, arch-linux

I added a ssd drive on my desktop computer and i start reinstalling arch on it. Usually, i make two partitions (`/` and `/home`) On my old install, i used 80GB for / and 300GB for /home before wiping my drive, i looked the occuped space on each partition and it appears that more or less 28GB were used on the / partition.

As i have a small SSD, i only have 30GB left for linux (windows is on the rest) on the ssd so i think adding an other partition on the HDD would be a good idea to prevent / to be full. The problem is : Which partition should i add : /var, /usr, other ? and why ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why -1 without any comment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do either: put *all* your data on the HDD, and then use the limited space on the SDD to cache your most commonly used data.

You can do this using LVM. It's a slightly complicated procedure to describe, but actually boils down to less than 10 commands. There's a good tutorial here: https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/using-lvms-new-cache-feature/

Essentially, what you end up with is roughly the same as those "hybrid" drives that contain both HDD and SDD in one.